# Node: Comments gawk: cmd. line:70: (FILENAME=../doc/m4.texinfo FNR=919) fatal: Invalid content of \{\}: /@tabchar{}/

Tags: awk

I have a problem with patching for opensource software vulnerable issues, it is a CVE-2008-1687 found in m4 opensource.

The log of problem is

> cd [build_DIR]/m4/1.4.9-r2/m4-1.4.9/checks && AWK=gawk ./get-them ../doc/m4.texinfo
>
> (....skip)
>
> Node: Comments gawk: cmd. line:70: (FILENAME=../doc/m4.texinfo FNR=919) fatal: `Invalid content of \{\}: /@tabchar{}/`

The log said that gawk command executed until line 918 of m4.texinfo file and `Invalid content of \{\}: /@tabchar{}/` error was occurred at line 919. But, the `\{\}` content and `/@tabchar{}/` character are not found at line 919 of m4.texinfo.
So, I'm wondering why the error was occurred and how can I fix it.

[get-them]

```
/^@example$/, /^@end example$/ {
if (seq < 0)
    next;
if ($0 ~ /^@example$/) {
    if (count > 0)
        close (file);
    seq++;
    count++;
    file = sprintf("%03d.%s", count, node);
    printf("dnl @ %s:%d: Origin of test\n"\
        "dnl @ expected status: %d\n"\
        "dnl @ Copyright (C) 2006, 2007 Free Software Foundation\n"\
        "dnl @ This file is free software; the Free Software Foundation\n"\
        "dnl @ gives unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it\n"\
        "dnl @ with or without modifications, as long as this notice\n"\
        "dnl @ is preserved.\n", FILENAME, NR, status) > file;
    status = 0;
    next;
}
if ($0 ~ /^@end example$/) {
    next;                                             // line 70
}
if ($0 ~ /^\^D$/)
    next;
if ($0 ~ '/^@result\{\}/' || $0 ~ '/^@error\{\}/')
    prefix = "dnl ";
else
    prefix = "";
gsub("@@", "@", $0);
gsub("@{", "{", $0);
gsub("@}", "}", $0);
gsub("@w{ }", " ", $0);
gsub("@tabchar{}", "\t", $0);
printf("%s%s\n", prefix, $0) >> file;
```

}

> [m4.texinfo]
>
> @node Comments
>   @section Comments in @code{m4} input
>
> @cindex comments
>   Comments in @code{m4} are normally delimited by the characters @samp{#}
>   and newline.  All characters between the comment delimiters are ignored,
>   but the entire comment (including the delimiters) is passed through to
>   the output---comments are @emph{not} discarded by @code{m4}.
>
> Comments cannot be nested, so the first newline after a @samp{#} ends
>   the comment.  The commenting effect of the begin-comment string
>   can be inhibited by quoting it.
>
> @example
>
> `quoted text' #`commented text'                        // line 919
>
> @result{}quoted text # `commented text'
>
> `quoting inhibits'`#' `comments'
>
> @result{}quoting inhibits # comments
>
> @end example

Comment: the error log is "Invalid content of `\{\} : @tabchar{} (\ is missing.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you indicate is line 70:

```
next;                                             // line 70
```

clearly is not line 70 of your awk script since it doesn't contain the text that the error message is telling you produced the failure at line 70:

```
Invalid content of \{\}: /@tabchar{}/
```

In the regexp in this code:

```
gsub("@tabchar{}", "\t", $0);
```

`{}` is an RE interval (as in `x{3}` means 3 repetitions of x) - it can't be empty and I suspect you wanted the `{` and `}` to be treated as literal anyway.

Look:

```
$ echo 'foo@tabchar{}bar' | awk 'gsub("@tabchar{}", "\t", $0);'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Invalid content of \{\}: /@tabchar{}/

$ echo 'foo@tabchar{}bar' | awk 'gsub("@tabchar\{\}", "\t", $0);'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\{' treated as plain `{'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\}' treated as plain `}'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Invalid content of \{\}: /@tabchar{}/

$ echo 'foo@tabchar{}bar' | awk 'gsub("@tabchar\\{\\}", "\t", $0);'
foo     bar
```

You need 2 escapes because you're using a string in a regexp context and so awk has to convert the string to a regexp first (using up one set of escapes) and THEN use it as a regexp (using the remaining set of escapes. Use regexp (`/.../`) instead of string (`"..."`) delimiters around regexps to avoid that and other problems:

```
$ echo 'foo@tabchar{}bar' | awk 'gsub(/@tabchar\{\}/, "\t", $0);'
foo     bar
```

You should also think about what you're trying to do with the single quotes around regexps in other parts of your script, e.g.:

```
if ($0 ~ '/^@result\{\}/' || $0 ~ '/^@error\{\}/')
```

I think you probably meant to write:

```
if ($0 ~ /^@result\{\}/ || $0 ~ /^@error\{\}/)
```

which is equivalent to just:

```
if (/^@result\{\}/ || /^@error\{\}/)
```

or even just:

```
if (/^@(result|error)\{\}/)
```

Comment: Very thanksful for your help Morton. :) I solved the problem using `gsub("@tabchar\\{\\}", "\t", $0)`. uhm..by the way, the code I modified was originally there, and it worked fine until I applied the patch, CVE-2008-1687. Also, the patch does not have contents about `@tabchar{}`. So, I'm wondering why the error was occurred after patching. Could you answer to this, please?

Comment: wrt "I solved the problem using `gsub("@tabchar\\{\\}", "\t", $0)`" - but I explained that the way to solve it was with `gsub(/@tabchar\{\}/, "\t", $0)` and explained why that was the right way to do it so why not just do that? wrt "the code was there and worked fine, etc." - idk what it is you're patching or what any of those numbers mean, all I can tell you is that that code and the other code in the script I pointed out has the bugs I mentioned.

Comment: okay,,sorry for that an excessive question. I modified using `gsub(/@tabchar\{\}/, "\t", $0)`. and again thank you for your help.